# How does llvm allocate and get element in union?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have the following C code and the IR for function `caller()`. Can anyone explain why it allocates `[2 x %struct.C]` for `karg1`? Or more generally, how LLVM optimize a union? And I'm confused with the GEP instructions of `%karg1.sub`.

```
int cmd = 1;
struct T
{
    int tuner;
    char name[32];
    unsigned long rangelow, rangehigh;  
    unsigned int flags;
    unsigned short mode;            
    unsigned short signal;          
};

struct C
{
    char    loadwhat[16];   
    int datasize;
    unsigned char   *data;
};

void f(struct C *kp){
    unsigned char *ud = kp->data;
    if(ud){
    }
}

void caller(){
    union{
        struct T vt;
        struct C vc;
    }karg;
    switch(cmd){
        case 1:
            f(&karg.vc);
    }
}
```

Resulting LLVM IR

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define void @caller() #0 {
/*why it allocate 2 x %struct.C*/
  %karg1 = alloca [2 x %struct.C], align 8 
  %1 = load i32, i32* @cmd, align 4
  switch i32 %1, label %3 [
    i32 1, label %2
  ]

; <label>:2                                       ; preds = %0
/*How to understand this gep instruction*/
  %karg1.sub = getelementptr inbounds [2 x %struct.C], [2 x %struct.C]* %karg1, i64 0, i64 0
  call void @f(%struct.C* %karg1.sub)
  br label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %2, %0
  ret void
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? What did you expect the resulting output to be? What's unclear about `getelementptr`?

Comment: Well, my question is, where does 2x come from?

Comment: @Crystal - To cover the size delta of the union  `karg` would be my guess. Did you have optimizations set when you genned the LLVM?

Comment: @FrankC. What is optimizations set? Do you mean the compile options? To cover the union... why not struct.C+struct.T or 2xstruct.T? I think T occupies more space.

Comment: I meant what is the command line options when you generated the LLVM-IR?

Comment: @Frank C. 
    `clang -emit-llvm -S test.c -o test.ll` 
    `opt -S -instcombine test.ll -o test.ll`
    `llvm-as test.ll -o test.bc`

Comment: OK, in 5.0.1 it allocates the union then does a `bitcast` to a struct C* and makes the call.

Comment: So, 2 x %struct.C means "allocates the union". Am I right?